# MVC: Changes to controller don't take effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Suddenly any changes to controller has stopped taking effect. I make changes to controller, build/rebuild the solution but the changes does not appear in browser. I even deleted almost all code inside action controller.

For example, I changed following code

```
public ActionResult Index(string txtSearch, int? page)
{
    var db = new DataContext();

    //db.CategoryInfo.ToArray();
    var list = from s in db.CategoryInfo
               select s;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch))
    {
        list = list.Where(s => s.txtTitle.Contains(txtSearch));
    }

    list = list.OrderBy(s => s.txtTitle);

    ViewBag.txtSearch = txtSearch;
    ViewBag.intCount = list.Count();

    int PageSize = 10;
    int PageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    return View(list.ToPagedList(PageNumber, PageSize));
}
```

to just

```
public ActionResult Index(string txtSearch, int? page)
{

    return View(list.ToPagedList(PageNumber, PageSize));
}
```

No error occured while rebuilding solution, and browser showed same results as before.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you try by closing Visual Studio and then restarting it? Also make sure that IISExpress (you can find it in icons of System Tray) stopped, or stop it manually.

Comment: I'm curious to how your controller even built though because you never declare your 'list' variable in the second code snippet. That should cause a compiler error and prevent from building and then you wouldn't see your changes.

Comment: It's impossible that your second part of code build because list isn't declared.

Answer (score 0):

First off you never declared your `list` variable in your second code snippet. That should cause a compiler error and prevent the build from being successful.

Secondly if you are building successfully (Which should not be possible if `list` is not declared somewhere) then try to clear your browser cache with CTRL+F5.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the browser cache. May be that's the reason for this. Also if you want you can try preventing of caching the controller -> actions by code as well.